# Make a created object equal to another again

Tags: c++, object, equals

I have two objects(a and b) initially, and b = a. Some operations is performed on a, and I'm wondering how can I make b = a again.

For example,

```
int main()
{
  A a;
  a.some_ops();
  /// I to create a new object and make it equal to a
  A b = a;
  b.some_ops();

  a.other_ops();
  /// Now I want to make b = a again 
  b = a; // BUG, this will not work, right?
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: To answer this, it's necessary to know how `A` is declared/defined. `b = a;` could work if `A` provides a sufficient `operator=()` (and this even could be the `default` assignment operator generated by the compiler). Did you get a compiler error? If not: did you observe unintended behavior in debugging?

Comment: Assignment is usually the way to copy an object.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you for your reply. Yes, I got a compiler error. The size of boost::multi_array does not matches, which is the variable of class A. I have lots of variable defined in A, if using operator=(), does it mean that I need to swap() each of the defined variable?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Thank you for your reply. This makes me clear. So in my code, I use A b = a, this is the copy constructor; if I want to use b = a, I need to use assignment, right? And in the assignment operator, I need to swap each defined variable in A, right?

Comment: OK. Your comment approached when I had the answer close to send. So, in this case your class has a member which is not assignable. You could overload assignment operator for `A` to handle this.

Comment: If you swap of not depends on if you pass the right-hand side of the assignment by value or by (possibly `const`) reference. If you pass by value then yes you can swap, since the object is temporary within the assignment operator function. If a `const` reference you can't. And if a non-`const` reference, you should not modify the right-hand side of the assignment.

Comment: Some programmer dude  Thank you for your reply and time. I find someone use copy constructor and this makes me confused. Assignment looks quite straightforward for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ generates a default assignment operator for each `class` which assigns an instance member by member (using the assignment operators of the member classes/types).

If this is not intended the assignment operator can be either deleted (then assignment is denied) or overloaded.

I enriched the OPs sample code a bit:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  private:
    int _mem1, _mem2;
  public:
    A(): _mem1(0), _mem2(0) { }
    A(const A&) = default;
    A& operator=(const A&) = default;
    void some_ops() { ++_mem1; }
    void other_ops() { ++_mem2; }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const A &a)
    {
      return out << "mem1: " << a._mem1 << ", mem2: " << a._mem2;
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "A a;\n"; A a;
  std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n';
  std::cout << "a.some_ops;\n"; a.some_ops();
  std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n';
  /// I to create a new object and make it equal to a
  std::cout << "A b = a;\n"; A b = a;
  std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
  std::cout << "b.some_ops();\n"; b.some_ops();
  std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';

  std::cout << "a.other_ops();\n"; a.other_ops();
  std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
  /// Now I want to make b = a again 
  std::cout << "b = a;\n"; b = a; // BUG, this will not work, right? <= It should.
  std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A a;
a: mem1: 0, mem2: 0
a.some_ops;
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 0
A b = a;
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 0, b: mem1: 1, mem2: 0
b.some_ops();
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 0, b: mem1: 2, mem2: 0
a.other_ops();
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 1, b: mem1: 2, mem2: 0
b = a;
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 1, b: mem1: 1, mem2: 1
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72ecb3c21de3e393)</kbd>

---

The first sample code – with overloaded copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  private:
    int _mem1, _mem2;
  public:
    A(): _mem1(0), _mem2(0) { }
    A(const A &a):
      _mem1(a._mem1), _mem2(a._mem2)
    {
      std::cout << "A::A(const A&) called\n";
    }
    A& operator=(const A &a)
    {
      _mem1 = a._mem1; _mem2 = a._mem2;
      std::cout << "A& A::operate=(const A&) called\n";
      return *this;
    }
    void some_ops() { ++_mem1; }
    void other_ops() { ++_mem2; }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const A &a)
    {
      return out << "mem1: " << a._mem1 << ", mem2: " << a._mem2;
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "A a;\n"; A a;
  std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n';
  std::cout << "a.some_ops;\n"; a.some_ops();
  std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n';
  /// I to create a new object and make it equal to a
  std::cout << "A b = a;\n"; A b = a;
  std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
  std::cout << "b.some_ops();\n"; b.some_ops();
  std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';

  std::cout << "a.other_ops();\n"; a.other_ops();
  std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
  /// Now I want to make b = a again 
  std::cout << "b = a;\n"; b = a; // BUG, this will not work, right? <= It should.
  std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A a;
a: mem1: 0, mem2: 0
a.some_ops;
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 0
A b = a;
A::A(const A&) called
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 0, b: mem1: 1, mem2: 0
b.some_ops();
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 0, b: mem1: 2, mem2: 0
a.other_ops();
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 1, b: mem1: 2, mem2: 0
b = a;
A& A::operate=(const A&) called
a: mem1: 1, mem2: 1, b: mem1: 1, mem2: 1
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/871bcadcbb5ef492)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. This is really helpful!